# How can I notify ReSharper that I've initialized [NotNull] fields?

Tags: c#, resharper

The follwing `TestClass` has a non-readonly field marked as `[NotNull]`.

ReSharper checks if I initialize the field in the constructor.

I'd like to keep the initialization code in a separate method `UpdateFields` to observe DRY principle. But ReSharper does not understand that.

How can I notify ReSharper that I've already initialized the fields? Can I use [`Contract Annotation`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Contract_Annotations.html) in any way?

```
    public class TestClass {
        [NotNull] private object notNull;

        //// ReSharper warns!
        public TestClass() {
            UpdateFields();
        }

        private void UpdateFields() {
            notNull = new object();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im guessing the static analysis is limited to the constructor (as you have discovered), Disable it with a `pragma` or resharper comment i guess

Comment: You're right. The customer support says so :(

Comment: Add all this information you have gathered to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the customer support of JetBrains, ReSharper does not have such an option.

Workaround is described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2019.1/NotNullMemberIsNotInitialized.html).